# Query not refetching after delete mutation

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have a simple delete mutation, which is supposed to refetch all the searches using the `RecentSearchesQuery`.

```
const onDeletePress = async (searchResultId: string) => {    
        await deleteSearch({
          variables: {
            _id: searchResultId,
          },
          refetchQueries: [{ query: RecentSearchesQuery }, "getUserSearches"],
        });
 };

  const {
    data: recentsData,
    error: recentsError,
    loading: recentsLoading,
  } = useQuery(RecentSearchesQuery, {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    nextFetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });
```

When checking my DB, i do see the search being deleted, but the `recentsData` contains the old data, and the `recentsLoading` isn't `true` after the mutation. I am using the same structure in other places in my code, which works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to track when react is updating your components vs. when the query is being attempted? Depending on the code, react state will update before a query that is needed to be run after which can result in behaviors like this.